# Movie/show about a crashed UFO seen in the 90s

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, ufos

A UFO crashes. Military guards it. An alien comes. We see from its point of view as it approaches a guard, who is shooting at it with an auto weapon, but in vain. Some bright flashes, and the soldier collapses.

Another scene, same point of view. The alien enters a house at night, approaches a sleeping person. The person wakes up, sees the alien, goes screaming, and then there's a cut.

The aliens are taller than humans, walk with slow, heavy steps which thud loudly.

I've no idea if it was color or b/w, because we had b/w tv back then:) Thinking of it, it must have been between 1989-91. I don't know how old it was at the time.
Also not sure if it was a movie or a show episode.
Dunno the language. It was most probably a German channel (sat1/pro7/rtl) where everything was dubbed.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site =) There's some good info about the plot and events here, but what about external factors, such as when the movie came out, who might have been in it, the target audience, was it a cartoon or live action, etc. etc. For more ideas about what to include try [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info)

Comment: color vs black and white, spoken language, etc...

Comment: any recall of alien features? For example, lizard, gray, etc...or humanoid (a la Day the Earth Stood Still) - just saying 'alien' doesn't even really mean anything unfortunately

Comment: Strange, but I can't remember how they looked like. There were only shots from their point of view maybe?

Comment: I don't know if it's of any help, but the scene with the alien entering a house might be just a nightmare of the person, from which he/she wakes up screaming. I don't know why I didn't think of it in the first place. Consequently, the other alien's-point-of-view scenes might also be only dreams.

Comment: Some of this is making me think of an oldie from 1966 called 'Invasion'.. however it's got to be 30 years since I last saw it and I can't recall enough. I know there was a soldier firing a sub machine gun as an alien approached